# Same position, no feedback over a month, should I reapply via a different recruiter?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment

I am in job search right now. I applied for a position via a recruiter over one month ago and got no feedback at all. Over the course I have called the recruiter every week to check if there is any news, good or bad, and did not get anything at all.

I know that a friend of mine was already interviewed one month ago for the same position. I had very similar background but stronger, yet I got no update at all. I do not know if the company is still reviewing my cv or if my cv ended up on their table at all.

Now my friend who was interviewed for the position recommended his recruiter to me and he likes my cv and background. Shall I apply for the position again via this new recruiter, seeing that he at least secured an interview for my friend?

Comment: No do not do that. THis is a guarantee that the company will not hire you because they will not pay two recruiters for the same opening. Move on.

Comment: Unless you have a totally different profile from the time you have applied I would not recommend you to apply through a different recruiter as it might get the company confused..

Comment: However, the first recruiter has given you a diabolical service and you should tell them to remove your records and not use your details any more and move on to a more professional recruitment company.

Comment: Reapplying is a bad idea. There's no way that will help you. Check in with your current application directly instead, if your recruiter isn't given you an answer one way ot the other.

Answer (score 11):

**Never try to use multiple recruiters for the same job.**

- You'll upset your first recruiter and burn a bridge.
- The second recruiter will find out when the company tells them that the first recruiter submitted the CV. You'll burn that bridge.
- The company will at worst see you as shady and at best see you as annoying. You'll likely burn that bridge too.

I can see no positives to doing what you're suggesting. If they were interested in you, they would have contacted your recruiter.

You need to just move on. There are other jobs.

Comment: Additionally, *always* have the recruiter tell you who the job is with, and if they refuse you tell them you're not interested.

Comment: Are you serious? You're flat out telling someone not to use all available means at his disposal to obtain something he really cares about because it might hurt the posible income or feelings of some guy he never met? All the while the other guy does whatever he can to maximize income with no regard for our OP? Is the recruiting world this blind? Or is it just you?

Comment: "'ll upset your first recruiter", recruiters are far too busy with other people to worry about one person finding another recruiter. I dont even see a reason to tell them if they are not even helping OP.
It also may make OP seem annoying, but he is clearly not going to benefit anything from waiting for his current recruiter to get him an interview.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally to Christopher Estep's answer:
You are also a party in job/applicant search. Waiting for a month for a simple answer or progress response is qualifying for over the reasonable time. Still it may prove to be just a long process. You should assess your priorities and options. If you feel your possibilites fitting for that, **you may send a notice** to the not responding recruiter that you are looking for a response in the following 7 days, and after that you continue to apply to different positions. This is a fair way to manage this type of situation.

I happened to apply a job, got employed elsewhere in the following 3 months, and 5 months later recieved an e-mail that they considered my CV and would like to have an interview with me. My thoughts:"Seriously? You expect me to wait at home 8 months?" Most probably they tried the better seeming applicants, and finally they got to my CV in the line.

Comment: I once was talking to an internal recruiter from a major railroad here in Atlanta and she told me that their hiring process was over 6 months long because of great benefits, etc. I told her no thanks and moved on, so I can echo the time thing you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

My perspective is different from the others here. From working in Staffing as a Recruiter, then in Corporate Recruiting, and now leading a Talent Acquisition group, what I've seen leads me to think you are fine to reach out to the 2nd Recruiter under a few conditions...

- Last-shot-loyalty... Give the original Recruiter a chance. I couldn't tell from your question whether you spoke with them or not yet. If not, it could just be a long process, so reach out and try to touch base.
- Stay honest... Call your friend's new Recruiter, but let them know the situation. Tell them that you are unsure as to whether your resume was submitted or not, but you would love to be represented by them.
- Respect... Stay respectful of everyone. You never know where paths cross, so don't talk down about the original Recruiter to the other Recruiter or the company.

**Some additional insights into the process:**

- Staffing companies use tons of different tactics, some of which can be frustrating. For example, the original Recruiter could have screened 5 finalists, but the client company might only take the top 3 from each vendor (which could be 3 others if you were number 4 or 5). So, this Recruiter's tactic would be to keep other good candidates like yourself on-the-hook so that a competitor company doesn't submit you to the client.
- Also, Recruiters with good relationships can have a casual conversation with the hiring manager or client company. The 2nd Recruiter could call up the hiring manager and ask if they have received your resume yet. This is very common, and it does not reflect poorly on anyone. If the manager has not received your resume, then the Recruiter can pass it along to them (WIN for you!). If the manager has received your resume, it might even subconsciously make the manager give the resume another look or think it's a good resume since 2 different Recruiters were trying to present it to them.

Answer (score 0):

Offering the perspective of the employee here: Recruiting is a service. If you don't pay for it, you're not the recipient of it.

It's safe to assume that the person that you contacted you for the position has the interests of the hiring company and his own in mind. Any action he does or does not take is to be judged with this thought in mind.

So as far as your situation goes, you are getting the classical Recruiter cold shoulder treatment. What they're saying is that you are not important (feedback to you is delayed or missing) and that you are also not interesting (even when you ping them for feedback, they provide little or none at all). Why they might be doing this should be of little importance to you, we already established your competencies and skills are worthless to this person and he will not make any effort to sell them to your potential employer. When this happens, your chances for a hire drop down dramatically.

My suggestion is to ignore everyone else's opinions and do what you think is right. If you consider you could be an asset to this specific employer and that that specific recruiter is hampering you and your employer from having a happy working relationship, just bypass them. Stick your foot in the door, either by working with a possible candidate (your friend could push your resume), someone in the company, or another recruiter.

If it's just another job, it's probably not worth pissing off recruiters. As you can see from the answers above, they own the world and bad things will happen to your karma if they don't get their bonuses.